# How to call Variable Column name in Laravel MYSQL Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

My concern:

```
if ($case=='private') {
    $langtitle = 'title';
    }
else {
     $langtitle='title_gov';
    }
```

if it is Government *(falls under else case above)* I want to select, `'title'` as well as `'title_gov'` with Select in query as,

```
Images::select($langtitle ,'id', 'title')
            ->groupBy('id')
            ->paginate('10');
```

If it is private, then only `'title'` to be selected. I do not want to use if else case for Query, instead I want to call it using Variable or regex or some method. How can I?

Comment: So you have in your **database: id / title / title_gov** and you want to select either *title* or *title_gov* based on the if statement?

Comment: @KGG Yes, if private, need to select *id and title* but if it is government I want to select *id, title, title_gov*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the When eloquent function

```
$query = Images::query();

$query->when(
    $case == 'private',
    function ($query) {
        return $query->select('title', 'id');
    },
    function ($query) {
        return $query->select('title_gov' ,'id', 'title'));
    }
)
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->paginate('10');
```

You can read more about it [here](https://laraveldaily.com/post/less-know-way-conditional-queries).

Comment: You cannot call the same column twice in SQL, you will get **Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'title'** which is what she was having problems with already.

Comment: oh, sorry a typo 
I updated my answer

Comment: Any short way? because if it is so, I can simply use the query within the questioned IF case.

Comment: I have removed the result variable, but I'm not sure if there is a shorter version of this.

maybe you could read the article I provide and you may see a cleaner way to write your query.
but If you don't want to use the `if else`, this is the way

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track, the only issue you were having is that when the case is `"private"` it will load the `column "title"` twice, instead you can do the following:

```
if ($case == 'private') {
    $langtitle = ['id', 'title'];
}else{
    $langtitle = ['id', 'title', 'title_gov'];
}
Images::select($langtitle)->groupBy('id')->paginate('10');
```

Comment: If it is not **private**, it will select: **id, title_gov** but I want **id, title, title_gov**.

Comment: if it is government, I want to select **id, title**only

Comment: **Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'field list'**

Comment: @AnonymousGirl My apologies, please check a different approach, as you can just pass an array based on the criteria